# Shell script to append folder names to the sub-folders and move them

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rename, batch-rename

I have several folders inside a directory called freesurfer like:

```
freesurfer/sub-001/mri
freesurfer/sub-001/label
freesurfer/sub-001/surf
freesurfer/sub-001/stats
freesurfer/sub-002/mri
freesurfer/sub-002/label
freesurfer/sub-002/surf
freesurfer/sub-002/stats
```

I would like to rename only 'stats' folder and move it to a different location:

```
freesurfer/sub-001/mri
freesurfer/sub-001/label
freesurfer/sub-001/surf
freesurfer/sub-001/sub-001_stats
freesurfer/sub-002/mri
freesurfer/sub-002/label
freesurfer/sub-002/surf
freesurfer/sub-002/sub-002_stats
```

I have managed to write the following code:

```
while read dir ; do 
    new_dir=$(rev <<< "$dir" | sed 's~/~_~' | rev); 
    echo "mv $dir $new_dir"; 
done < <(find . -type d -name 'stats')
```

The above code seems to be working fine when I run it with 'echo' before 'mv' command and appends the folder name in front of 'stats' directory but when I take the 'echo' off, it gives an error saying: "No such file or directory".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you removed the `echo`, did you also remove the quotes? It should be `mv "$dir" "$new_dir"`

Comment: WHen I try your code, I get `freesurfer/sub-002_stats` not `freesurfer/sub-002/sub-002_stats`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to create `new_dir` isn't correct. It's creating `freesurfer/sub-002_stats` instead of `freesurfer/sub-002/sub-002_stats`. But this doesn't explain the error you're getting, since it will just rename the file incorrectly (moving all of them into the parent directory).

Try:

```
while read dir ; do 
    new_dir=$(dirname "$dir")/$(basename $(dirname "$dir"))_stats
    mv "$dir" "$new_dir"
done < <(find . -type d -name 'stats')
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much. you were right, I was skipping a directory level which caused the error